# What are the differences between setFilterQueryProvider() and runQueryOnBackgroundThread() in CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I don't quite understand, is the provider means ContentProvider? Or I think they are the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are comparing a Banana and an Elephant. The difference is: they are not the same at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for those methods is pretty clear:

*Runs a query with the specified constraint. This query is requested by the filter attached to this adapter. The query is provided by a FilterQueryProvider. If no provider is specified, the current cursor is not filtered and returned. After this method returns the resulting cursor is passed to changeCursor(android.database.Cursor) and the previous cursor is closed. This method is always executed on a background thread, not on the application's main thread (or UI thread.) Contract: when constraint is null or empty, the original results, prior to any filtering, must be returned.*

Under the hood the `runQueryOnbackgroundThread()` method simply runs the `runQuery()` method of the `FilterQueryProvider` if one is provided. You would use the `FilterQueryProvider` when you need to filter the `CursorAdapter` without creating a subclass, if you extend `CursorAdapter` you could choose between still providing a `FilterQueryProvider` or overriding the `runQueryOnbackgroundThread()` method.

`FilterQueryProvider` has nothing to do with a `ContentProvider`:

*This class can be used by external clients of CursorAdapter and CursorTreeAdapter to define how the content of the adapter should be filtered.*

Comment: OK. Thank you for you reply. I think I understand more now.
So if I try something like
'adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
   @Override
   public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
    ...
   }
  });'
Then 'adapter.getFilter().filter(s);'
and 'adapter.runQueryOnBackgroundThread(s);'
will be the same, right?

Comment: So if what I want to do is filtering the Cursor I get in the adpater.getCursor(), what I should use is getFilter() instead of setFilterQueryProvider() to avoid re-query, right?

Comment: @OwenZhao You're confusing terms. The methods `runQueryOnBackgroundThread()` and `setFilterQueryProvider()` are used when the adapter is filtered to provide the new query. When you call `getFilter().filter(s)` the `CursorAdapter`'s `Filter` will run the `runQueryOnBackgroundThread()` method which in turn will call the `runQuery()` method of the `FilterQueryProvier` if one is provided.

Comment: So I guess there is not a solution that I can just filter the Cursor but not re-query the database. What I want is to re-query the Cursor as the Cursor is in the memory so it will be very quick. Thank you for all your replies.

Comment: @OwenZhao *What I want is to re-query the Cursor as the Cursor is in the memory so it will be very quick* - nope, you can't do this you'll need to requery the database. You can however keep on your own the `Cursor` with all the data and create an adapter based on a list of data and you'll retrieve the proper data from the Cursor when you want to filter it. Of course this has its drawbacks.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the replies that @Luksprog give to me. Also, I have read the source codes of CursorAdapter, CursorFilter and Filter.
It turns out that CursorFilter extends Filter, and CursorAdapter implements Filterable and CursorFilter.CursorFilterClient.

So if you call `getFilter.filter(s)`, you will get the new cursor, and reset the CursorAdapter to the new cursor automatically.

But if you call `runQueryOnBackgroundThread(s)`, you only got a new cursor. So you need not to call it manually.

Also, since filter will call `runQueryOnBackgroundThread(s)` and `runQueryOnBackgroundThread(s`) will call `FilterQueryProvider.runQuery(s)`. The best way to set you re-query code is by calling

```
CursorAdpapter adapter;
adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            ...
            return db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
        }
    });
```

Then use `adapter.getFilter().filter(s);` when you need a re-query.

Comment: @zack Not by itself alone.  However, it will be called by runQueryOnBackgroundThread(s) by design. So unless you call it directly, it always runs in a background thread.

Comment: So in your code above, `runQuery()` is actually running in a background thread, because it's internally being called by `runQueryOnBackgroundThread()` right?

Comment: @zack True. You get it.

Comment: Hi, I'm working on an old code that uses setFilterQueryProvider , and for some reason the `runQuery` is used on the UI thread. Any idea what could cause it? I tried to debug and couldn't find what triggered it on the app. What is supposed to trigger it? I don't see `runQueryOnBackgroundThread` being used, but I do see `getFilter().filter()` being used...